# Add new pandas DataFrame column whose values are an array of random numbers with length gleaned from another column

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have the following DataFrame of dummy data

```python
data = { 'user_id': np.random.randint(1000000, 10000000, size=(10)), 'week': np.random.randint(1, 10, size=(10)) }
df = pd.DataFrame(data = data)
```

I would like to add a new column whose values are arrays of length `week` (with those arrays containing random values). None of these work

```python
df.loc[:,'inputs'] = np.random.randint(0, 28, size=(10))
```

(gives one integer per DataFrame cell, not an array of them)

```python
df.loc[:,'inputs'] = np.random.randint(0, 28, size=(df['week']))
```

> ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

```python
df.loc[:,'inputs'] = np.random.randint(0, 28, size=(10, df['week']))
```

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

These are obviously all wrong, but I cannot see how to make a new column whose entries are each arrays where the length of those arrays depends on another column's value in the same row.

Comment: Language tag please

Comment: @MadPhysicist, I think a language tag would be misleading, this is not a general Python question, it is specific to pandas. I'll edit the title to make that clearer

Comment: There's no way you can use pandas without python. Well, not by normal means at least.

Comment: Indeed, but there are lots of ways of writing Python without pandas. This question would only be of interest to people writing pandas, not all Python programmers, hence the tags.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289201/should-i-add-a-programming-language-tag-to-questions-about-frameworks

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/32450/178985

Comment: Python is not JavaScript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use list comprehension for arrays by `week` numbers:

```python
df['inputs'] = [np.random.randint(0, 28, size=x) for x in df['week']]
print (df)
```

```
   user_id  week                             inputs
0  9168288     4                     [15, 5, 10, 9]
1  2765768     7          [21, 26, 6, 6, 22, 21, 4]
2  2948278     6               [6, 14, 4, 2, 3, 20]
3  9302275     1                               [23]
4  5737115     5                 [1, 20, 9, 19, 18]
5  5214343     9  [16, 25, 1, 10, 2, 23, 1, 16, 18]
6  9332184     7          [8, 27, 14, 8, 14, 11, 5]
7  1569483     5                 [6, 19, 3, 10, 16]
8  2931319     2                            [0, 15]
9  2126334     2                           [20, 22]
```

Comment: Thanks for trying, but this is not what I asked for. I want each entry in the 'inputs' column to be an array of length `df['week']`

Comment: @dumbledad - It is what you need?